# The apt update in deepin 15.11 failed

Tags: apt, upgrade, repository, deepin

I use the deepin 15.11 and change the /etc/apt/source.list to

```
deb [by-hash=force] http://mirrors.aliyun.com/deepin lion main contrib non-free
```

according to the alibaba's official guide,but when I use `apt update`,here comes the error

```
Ign:1 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/deepin lion InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Err:3 http://mirrors.aliyun.com/deepin lion Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 222.186.18.240 80]
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.aliyun.com/deepin lion Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I once succeeded in `apt update` but today it failed. I don't know why, can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.aliyun.com/deepin lion Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Mean the `lion` directory in `http://mirrors.aliyun.com/deepin` doesn't exist.

The [deepin repository](http://mirrors.aliyun.com/deepin/dists/) accept `apricot` (aka `stable`) and `unstable`.

Edit your `sources.list` as follow:

```
deb [by-hash=force] http://mirrors.aliyun.com/deepin apricot main contrib non-free
```

or:

```
deb [by-hash=force] http://mirrors.aliyun.com/deepin stable main contrib non-free
```

[deppin: source configuration](https://wiki.deepin.org/wiki/Software_source#Source_configuration)